# После загрузки сайта на хостинг изменения в javascript не сохраняются

Tags: javascript, хостинг

я загрузила сайт по макету на хостинг, и слайдер перестал нормально работать, хотя на компьютере когда включаешь, все работает нормально. Оказалось, что изменения, которые я внесла в файл js уже на хостинге, не подгружаются на сам сайт, хотя на хостинге они сохранены. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано? Ссылка на сайт https://nachivot.ru/

Comment: Возможно ваш файл закешировался. После каждого изменения файла можете поменять его название и тогда каждый раз будет подгружаться актуальный файл

Comment: @EzioMercer, проще менять query параметр в html, каждый раз переименовывать файл никаких названий не хватит

Comment: @Grundy Ну можно и так :) У нас в прошлой компании сборщик автоматически менял названия файлов, добавляя к ним окончания, потому это первое пришло в голову. Но да, если вручную, то менять query параметры намного проще

Comment: Спасибо, этот способ сработал (с изменением имени файла)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решается добавлением нового текста в query-параметр ссылки (достаточно на dev'e поставить туда таймстамп и все изменения будут подтягиваться. не забудьте отключить когда перестанете изменять фронт, иначе файлы будут постоянно загружаться на клиенте (это в случае если вы поставите таймстамп)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css?v=1.1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1.1">
    <title>Roboschool</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Курсы по роботехнике для начальной школы">
    <script defer="" src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Comment: Немного не поняла, если честно. Что мы добавляем и куда?

Comment: @Bemfes `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1.1">` после знака вопроса